# How to get desired javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have a JavaScript string `sentrptg2c#appqueue#sentrptg2c#vwemployees#`

I want to get last part of the string: `vwemployees` through RegExp or from any JavaScript function.

and also want to remove that last keyword from string so that next time string will be like this `sentrptg2c#appqueue#sentrptg2c#`

I have tried

```
var str = "sentrptg2c#appqueue#sentrptg2c#vwemployees#";
var array = url.split('/');
var lastsegment = array[array.length-1];
```

and get `vwemployees` last segment but the string remains the same

```
sentrptg2c#appqueue#sentrptg2c#vwemployees#
```

It should be `sentrptg2c#appqueue#sentrptg2c#` when above code runs.

Please suggest a way to do this in JavaScript

Comment: You know `String.split()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/ykBCG/

```
var str = "sentrptg2c#appqueue#sentrptg2c#vwemployees#";
//Assuming # as seperator 
var array = str.split('#');

//Clear empty value in array
var newArray = array.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
var lastsegment = newArray[newArray.length-1];
alert(lastsegment);

//output is "vwemployees"
```

Answer (score 1):

use `split()` , `splice()` to remove from array and `join()` to join them back again

```
var str="sentrptg2c#appqueue#sentrptg2c#vwemployees#";
var reqvalue=str.split('#');
alert(reqvalue[3]); 
 reqvalue.splice(3,1);
 alert(reqvalue.join('#'))
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/mnRAc/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var str = "sentrptg2c#appqueue#sentrptg2c#vwemployees#";
  var arr = str.split("#");
  alert(arr[arr.length-2]);
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

split function will do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

The split function can help you: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
yourString.split("#");
```

You will get an array with your values: sentrptg2c,appqueue,sentrptg2c,vwemployees

After that you just have to remove the last element, and rebuild your string from this array.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "sentrptg2c#appqueue#sentrptg2c#vwemployees#";
alert(str);
var arr = str.split('#');
var lastsegment = arr[arr.length-2];
alert(lastsegment);
var new_str = str.replace(lastsegment+'#', '');
alert(new_str);
```